# wysihtml5 editor - not styling buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement the [bootstrap-wysihtml5](https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/) editor, but none of the buttons are showing up styled:

I am including scripts from the gitrepo downloads for [wysihtml5](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5), [bootstrap-wysihtml5](https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/), and the [official bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthewpeckham/cDXKZ/)

```
<?php

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>wysihtml5</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style>
    body {
        padding-top: 70px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">wysihtml5</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form method="post" action="submit-content.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea id="wysihtml5" class="form-control" rows="20" placeholder="Enter text..."></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-right">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Article</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/wysihtml5-0.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-wysihtml5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#wysihtml5').wysihtml5();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buttons miss the `btn-default` class, as it is needed in Bootstrap 3.

You can provide a template for buttons [like shown in documentation](https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/#custom-templates-for-toolbar-buttons), or by adding the class afterwards via jQuery.

Or even better fork the project and update it to bootstrap 3, and consider making a pull request to original repository then.

Comment: How do I add the `btn-default` class when all the buttons are generated through the javascript file(s)?

Comment: After creating templates, I realised it was actually easier to edit the classes straight within `bootstrap-wysihtml5.js` -- so thank you!